# AngularJS $http response data structure varies

Tags: angularjs

I am doing an $http call in angularjs as

```
  url="data/someJson.json";
  $http.get(url).then(function(data){
      var requiredContent = data.requiredContent;// Case 1
      var requiredContent = data.data.requiredContent; // Case 2
    });
```

And the content of someJson are as `{"requiredContent": {"a":"b"}};`

Is there any particular reason for getting data at different levels as shown above? In Some cases I get data as in case 1 and in others i get as in case 2. I do not know the reason for such behaviour. Kindly help me in understanding this behaviour.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using ? This seems like an odd bug.

Comment: The angular version is v1.2.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing the callbacks `then` and `success` of the `$http` promise. Take a look at the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kiwbCmSqnySQoyPfXgL5?p=preview)

The difference between these callbacks are the arguments. The `then` method is called with one parameter, namely an object representing the response. However, the 'success' method is called with 4 parameters: `data, status, headers, config`.

This means that if you are using the `then` callback you have to explicitly take the `data` property of the first argument to get the response data. If you are using the `success` callback the response data is directly stored in the first parameter.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) is a link to the relevant part of the angular documentation. Please also take a look at the paragraph beneath the second example.